# sort dict objects according to property inside an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have the Player class that has a profit priority.
I want to sort this requested_players dictionary:

```
requested_players = [
        {
            'player': Player("20801", "Cristiano Ronaldo", 93, 520000),
            'priority': 0
        },
        {
            'player': Player("173731", "Gareth Bale", 85, 9000),
            'priority': 0
        },
        {
            'player': Player("158023", "Lionel Messi", 94, 490000),
            'priority': 0
        }
    ]
```

according to that priority field.
I have tried to use the sorted method.This is how I started:

```
sorted(list(map(lambda player: player['player'].profit,requested_players)),key=????)
```

I am stuck here - not sure if the lambda is correct though

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass the function as `key` argument and not use `map`:

```
sorted(requested_players, key=lambda player: player['player'].profit)
```